# how to update only few columns of a table in spring jdbc template

Tags: spring, spring-jdbc

i am using spring jdbc template and i want to update some of the columns in a table.

Ex:Consider Student table

```
id-->1007.
name-->Krish.
age-->25.
tel-->0112538956536.
```

this is a existing record.i want to update some fields only(updating fields change time to time).others should have their existing values.how can i acheive this in Spring JDBC template.Any suggestions will be very much helpful.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

you can use jdbc template for update table from application

here is the simple example

```
String name = "asdads";
int age = 12;
String tel = "+905655465465";
int id = 1;

 String SQL = "update Student set name = ?, age= ? ,tel=?, last_updated = sysdate()  where id = ?";
 jdbcTemplate.update(SQL,name, age, tel, id);
```

Answer (score 0):

may be just like

```
jdbcTemplate.update(
        "update Student set last_updated=now(),some_field=?",
        "some value");
```